# Where to find queues and addresses created using artemis create in Apache ActiveMQ Artemis

Tags: java, activemq-artemis

I have created addresses and queues in Apache ActiveMQ Artemis using `artemis.cmd create` option. But when I check my `broker.xml` I don't find any address and queue I have created using `artemis.cmd` though when I start broker I can see all of them on Artemis console. Now I want to replicate same configuration to another server as is and having large number of queues it will be difficult to create all the queues on another server. Is there any option to dump to `broker.xml` and I can use it on another server or any other option to replicate these queues to another server?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When addresses and/or queues are added programmatically (e.g. via the management API) they are stored in the journal, specifically in one of the "bindings" files. The definitions are not written back to the XML.

If you want to reproduce these resources on another broker you can use the `data exp` and `data imp` commands to export and import them respectively from one broker to another.

Aside from that you could use an XML templating tool (e.g. [Apache FreeMarker](https://freemarker.apache.org/)) to generate the `broker.xml` with all the necessary resources.

Comment: You should create a new question for this.

Comment: Created new question here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59745396/apache-activemq-artemis-issue-connecting-windows-client-to-linux-server

Comment: Is there an example anywhere showing how to use data exp and data imp to exports the set of addresses and queues and import them into a new Artemis instance?

Comment: I'm not aware of any specific examples. The commands are pretty simple and straight-forward.