# Apache ActiveMQ Artemis issue connecting Windows client to Linux Server

Tags: java, activemq-artemis

My Apache ActiveMQ Artemis 2.10.1 server is running on Linux. When I am connecting to server with `activemq-client-5.14.5.jar` using the URL `failover:(tcp://x.x.x.1:61616,tcp://x.x.x.2:61616)?randomize=false;priorityBackup=true` from Linux messages are being consumed and posted without any error and consumer count updated on console. But when I try to connect to same servers from Windows Server 2016 with same URL, I get warning on the server side:

```
AMQ212037: Connection failure to /x.x.x.3:51126 has been detected: AMQ229014: Did not receive data from /x.x.x.3:51126 within the 30,000ms connection TTL. The connection will now be closed. [code=CONNECTION_TIMEDOUT]
```

There are no errors on client and consumer count does not increase on web console. What could be wrong in this case?

Comment: What version of ActiveMQ Artemis are you using?

Comment: Also, what specific client libraries are you using from the Linux server and from the Windows server?

Comment: @JustinBertram ActiveMQ Artmis version is 2.10.1 and client libraries are same on both Linux and Windows server `activemq-client-5.14.5.jar`. Same config works when ActiveMQ Artemis is running on Windows.

Comment: Seems like maybe there's an environmental or network issue of some kind preventing the connection from working properly from the client on Windows. I can't imagine how or why the same client would behave differently on a different platform if we only consider the client code itself.

Comment: I have tested this with different configurations for two days but still getting same error. Would it work if I change client jar `activemq-client-5.14.5.jar` to `artemis-jms-client-all-2.10.1.jar`?

Comment: If you're just testing different client configurations you're likely not getting at the environmental or network issue that could be the culprit here. I can't say whether or not the Artemis Core JMS client (i.e. artemis-jms-client-all-2.10.1.jar) would work given the failures you're seeing with the OpenWire JMS client (i.e. activemq-client-5.14.5.jar). That said, there's no reason to use the legacy OpenWire JMS client unless you're migrating older application and you simply want to avoid updating them. If you're developing a new application I'd recommend using the core JMS client.